# wordpress front end multi upload that does same as in back end

Tags: wordpress, image-uploading

I have made a custom registration form at front end. I want to show the same uploading functionality as in back end. I am not sure how to add the multiple upload thing at front end.
any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="#" class="custom_media_upload">Upload</a>
<img class="custom_media_image" src="" />
<input class="custom_media_url" type="text" name="attachment_url" value="">
<input class="custom_media_id" type="text" name="attachment_id" value="">
```

jQuery Code :

```
$('.custom_media_upload').click(function() {

var send_attachment_bkp = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;

wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment) {

    $('.custom_media_image').attr('src', attachment.url);
    $('.custom_media_url').val(attachment.url);
    $('.custom_media_id').val(attachment.id);

    wp.media.editor.send.attachment = send_attachment_bkp;
}

wp.media.editor.open();

return false;       
});
```

Answer (score 3):

user insert_attachment of wordpress to save attachment, then you will also have the functionality to get the images with different styles, get_attachment(id, 'full/medium/thumbnail').

```
    $files = $_FILES['upload_attachment'];
    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
      $newupload = insert_attachment($file,null);
      // save the $newupload with you from data, as psot id for the attachment
     }
     function  insert_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$setthumb='false') {

        // check to make sure its a successful upload
        if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

          require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
          require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
          require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
          $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );

       if ($setthumb) update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
         return $attach_id;
     }
```

in html , if you submit the form, images will be uploaded and referances will be saved in wp_post table

```
  <form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="upload_attachment[]" id="file"><br>
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="upload_attachment[]" id="file"><br>
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="upload_attachment[]" id="file"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: I am looking for the image upload button so as i can upload images front front end.

Comment: this is complete solution, will provide you the facility to upload multiple image from front end page,

Comment: I want the same popup to open as in back end. i.e at the back end when i click to add media, a pop up bis opened where it says drag files and other various options that are available at the back end . i want that same popup to load front end.